# Why is this python code giving NZEC at HackerEarth?

Tags: python, runtime-error

```
T = int(raw_input())

for t in xrange(T):
    N = int(raw_input())
    print N+1
    print N*(N+1)/2
    for x in range(0,N+1):
        print x,
    print ''
```

I am getting NZEC for this code on HackerEarth.
It is supposed to print the count, sum and nos between a range.

```
Sample Input :
1 // T
12 // N

Sample Output :
13
78
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Comment: If `raw_input()` returns "1 // T", then `int(raw_input())` will crash with a ValueError. Is that the exact literal sample input?

Comment: No... Those are just for info. The actual input is : 1 & 12 only

Comment: @LokiBgii Can you please attach the question link?