# compilation log ok but there is run time error! python programming challenge

Tags: python, input, runtime-error

after learning a lot about python I moved to solve some programming problem. I am ok with writing normal scripts but when it comes to programing problems I ruined. After trying some problem and **getting runtime-error** I thought there would be a problem with code but soon I started Google and found there is problem with input that how it is taken. I searched and view some question on stackoverflow but that doesn't help.
 Now taking about a particular problem I am trying to solve the below problem.

> You are given an array A of size N, and Q queries to deal with. For each query, you are given an integer X, and you're supposed to find out if X is present in the array A or not.
>
> Input:
>   The first line contains two integers, N and Q, denoting the size of array A and number of queries. The second line contains N space separated integers, denoting the array of elements Ai. The next Q lines contain a single integer X per line.
>
> Output:
>   For each query, print YES if the X is in the array, otherwise print NO.
>
> Sample input
>   5 6 
>   50 40 30 20 10 
>   10
>   20
>   30
>   40
>   50
>   100
>
> Sample Output
>   YES
>   YES
>   YES
>   YES
>   YES
>   NO

**(this is neither my homework nor I am getting reward)** 
 
 this is the solution i tried.

```
import sys  
p=[]
A=[]
file_name=sys.argv[1]
f= open(file_name)
user_args= f.read()
user_input=user_args.split()
N,n=int(user_input[0]), int(user_input[1])
for i in range(2,N+2):
    A.append(int(user_input[i]))
for i in range(N+2,n+N+2):
    p.append(int(user_input[i]))
for i in range(0,int(n)):
    linearsearch(A, p[i])
sys.exit()
#and then writing the linearsearch(A,p) for checkign the element.
```

that I tried and got compilation-log ok with runtime-error. Everything is ok if i run this code on my machine but when i submit it then this runtime error.
 
 I also searched for this error but no idea why am I getting this?

Here some user are suggesting the solution. what I want is feedback on code I have already written and as I tried in this to read the input from a file via command line.Where am I mistaking? Am I lacking some basics?

Comment: [this is complete output log that I am getting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gazZh.jpg)                                                            thanks

Comment: and I have seen post like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695107/why-is-this-python-code-giving-nzec-at-hackerearth ) so don't put them again

Comment: hackerearth.com link in inaccessible...

Comment: Is it a problem with their server? How are you running it? Are you sure that it's not just a problem with formatting? We can't tell what is going on here from what you have said so far.

Comment: I guess your algorithm is O(n²), so it is blowing up for large inputs. Try to make your algorithm O(log n) or better.

Comment: ok that require login so I pasted it [here](http://pastebin.com/d0PMmBzT) and [here](http://i.imgur.com/ZJdYRxh.jpg?1) check this

Comment: I put the another links please check that. @wogsland

Comment: Please read these two sections from the help center: [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Everything should be contained in your question, not just through links: the problem you're trying to solve, your code, your expected results, your actual results.

Comment: @skrrgwasme I improved the formatting. Check it and let this figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are supposed to read from stdin, not from a file - this will not work:

```
file_name=sys.argv[1]
f= open(file_name)
```

The skeleton of the solution should be something like this:

```
n, q = raw_input().split()
a = raw_input().split()
for query in sys.stdin:
    query.strip()
    if test_if_query_in(a):
        print "YES"
    else:
        print "NO"
```

Have fun writing `test_if_query_in`. The solution is very easy in Python because there is a builtin collection type with O(1) search.

Comment: what if I want to read the input from input.txt via command line?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK most judges require reading from STDIN, not file. @SajjjanKumar

Comment: @SajjjanKumar use shell redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You should use raw_input for reading data.
For example my solution is:

```
N,Q = map(int, raw_input().split(' '))
arr = map(int, raw_input().split(' '))
arr = set(arr)

for i in xrange(Q):
    N = int(raw_input())
    if N in arr:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```